# iCloud connects on simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, icloud

i'm new in programming iOS and now I have got the problem that I couldn't get a iCloud connection if I run my app on a real device.
The app runs perfect on the simulator and also if I disconnect the device from my mac.
Have anybody an idea how I can fix it?
This is the code I have written to connect to the iCloud

```
    self.fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        self.ubiquityIdentifier = [self.fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    });

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(self.ubiquityIdentifier)
        {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kiCloudAvailableNotification object:self.ubiquityIdentifier];
            [self startMediaQuery];
        }
        else
        {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kiCloudNotAvailableNotification object:self.ubiquityIdentifier];
            NSLog(@"iCloud not available");
        }
    });
```

If the device is connected I only go in the else block and if I test it in the simulator or on a not connected device everything works fine.
Thanks a lot.
weissja19

Comment: Can you please share how you're connecting to iCloud and maybe where it tends to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming* that you're detecting failure because that `NSLog` prints its "iCloud not available" message, you're setting up a classic race condition here:

1. You **set** the value of `self.ubiquityIdentifier` on a global (non-main) queue.
2. You **test** the value `self.ubiquityIdentifier` on the main queue.

The two `dispatch_async` calls run on different queues. As a result, there's no guarantee that you're setting the value of `self.ubiquityIdentifier` before you test it. It will work sometimes, and fail at others, and not necessarily for any obvious reason. When you get the "iCloud not available" message, it's because the second queue checked the value before you assigned any value.

The fix is to change the dispatch calls so that you can guarantee the order of execution. Two possibilities are:

1. Combine these two `dispatch_async` calls so that all of the code happens on the same queue, or
2. Move the second `dispatch_async` *inside* the first, so that you don't dispatch back to the main queue until you've set a value for `self.ubiquityIdentifier`.